# How do I retrieve the input into my text box from my GUI and store it in a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, input, user-input, return-value

I am new to Python and need a little assistance with. I need help with retrieving the input from my text box and storing it in a variable. This is what I currently have for my GUI. Basically I just want to return the input from each text box and store it in a variable. I thought since I used "return like_userInput" that I would just be able to store the input in that variable but it is not working. Any information would be greatly appreciated. I am still extremely new to programming and would love any feedback that you may have for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

# this is the function called when the button is clicked
def btnClickFunction():
    print('Submitted information to script.')


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    like_userInput = like_input.get()
    return like_userInput


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    comment_userInput = comment_input.get()
    return comment_userInput


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    follow_userInput = follow_input.get()
    return follow_userInput



root = Tk()

# This is the section of code which creates the main window
root.geometry('652x414')
root.configure(background='#00F5FF')
root.title('InstaBot')


# This is the section of code which creates a button
Button(root, text='Submit', bg='#F702D9', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), 
command=btnClickFunction).place(x=280, y=287)

Label(root, text='Powered by Zephyr', bg='#00F5FF', foreground='#F702D9', font=('arial', 20, 
'bold')).place(x=190, y=10)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Number of Likes', bg='#00F5FF', font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).place(x=125, y=110)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='% of Comments', bg='#00F5FF', font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).place(x=128, y=130)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='% of Follows', bg='#00F5FF', font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).place(x=138, y=150)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
like_input=Entry(root)
like_input.place(x=350, y=115)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
comment_input=Entry(root)
comment_input.place(x=350, y=135)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
follow_input=Entry(root)
follow_input.place(x=350, y=155)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given all your get input functions (getInputBoxValue) the same name. You will need to change each of them to be unique else python will only execute the last function definition everytime.

```
# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    like_userInput = like_input.get()
    return like_userInput


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    comment_userInput = comment_input.get()
    return comment_userInput


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInputBoxValue():
    follow_userInput = follow_input.get()
    return follow_userInput
```

Comment: I've now got it to work, thank you for that!! If I print the return value of the function it will come back with an int but when I try to implement it into my script it doesn't come back as an int - it looks more like hex code.. currently trying to resolve that now.

Comment: @zxcharyy - you are welcome.! 
Because this answer worked for you , please mark it as accepted.